# Map cp850 to unicode in Python

Tags: python, unicode

Is it possible to map cp850 to unicode in python? You might ask, why i want to do that: I got a textfile using cp850 and i have to create a database out of it. So there are used some characters used for text-formatting, for example █ (CP850: 0xDB) is used as a line-break. So i have converted the file to UTF-8 first to make it better human readable. Next step would be to fill the database and change the special characters to suitable control-chars (\n,\t,...). But the converting process (of course) causes a change in its numerical representation, for example for the line break from 0xDB to 0x2588. Is there a solution to fix this? Or do i have to map the codes myself?

Thanks

Comment: Since you’ve converted the file to UTF-8, why do you still want the CP850 representation of the `u'\u2588'` character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to map cp850 to unicode in python?

Sure, just decode the bytes of your data (Python 3 examples):

```
>>> s=b'\xcdABCDEF\xcd\xdbHIJKLMNOP'.decode('cp850')
>>> s
'═ABCDEF═█HIJKLMNOP'
```

> do i have to map the codes myself?

Just the bytes you need to translate.  There is a convenient `.translate` method for Unicode strings that takes a dictionary of the mappings:

```
>>> D={}
>>> D['\u2588'] = '\n'   # Make translation entry in dictionary
>>> s.translate(D)
'═ABCDEF═\nHIJKLMNOP'
```

When you're done, encode the output in UTF-8:

```
>>> s.translate(D).encode('utf8')
b'\xe2\x95\x90ABCDEF\xe2\x95\x90\nHIJKLMNOP'
```

The key point is to decode to Unicode when reading data in, do all the processing in Unicode, then encode back to data when sending data to storage.  For example, to a file:

```
with open('out.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Comment: shouldn't it be "encoding='cp850'" when writing back to file then?

Comment: @DoneDataSolutions The OP already converted the file to UTF-8. Read the question.